# Как работают транзакции в MS SQL в конкретных случаях?

Tags: sql-server, transaction

У меня есть несколько вопросов касательно транзакций MS SQL.

1. Выполняются ли транзакции в режиме автофиксации если команда помещена в явную транзакцию.
   То есть

   BEGIN TRANSACTION firstTran
   UPDATE Test1
   SET Value *= 10;
   COMMIT TRANSACTION

Будет ли UPDATE выполнятся в отдельной подтранзакции или нет?

2. Какие типы команд помещаются в автофиксирующие транзакции, знаю что из DML - INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE - есть ли ещё какие-то?
3. Уровни изоляции транзакций влияют на то, какие блокировки накладываются на объекты, а влияют ли они отношение транзакции к другим блокировкам?
4. Как я понял, суть оптимистичных уровней изоляции в отсутствии блокировок в замен на загруженность tempdb. А как это пересекается с обновлениями данных - на них накладывается монопольная блокировка? Если да, то учитывают ли эту блокировку другие транзакции с тем же уровнем изоляции при чтении и обновлении?